# Copy list from one class to a new list in another class

Tags: c#, list

I have a `List<String>` in the class Reader, which is initialized and have a get method:

```
private List<string> Temperature = new List<string>();

public List<String> GetTemperature()
{
    return Temperature;
}
```

I would like to copy the list from the `Reader` class to a new list in my `MainWindow` class.

I have tried the code below, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Temperature.Add(reader.GetTemperature());
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You are trying to add a list to a list. The only thing you can add to a list is an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are coping to a new list, then you can also use the constructor of the class [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Temperature = new List<string>(reader.GetTemperature());
```

> Initializes a new instance of the `List<T>` class that contains elements
>   copied from the specified collection and has sufficient capacity to
>   accommodate the number of elements copied.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like:

```
Temperature.AddRange(reader.GetTemperature());
```

> Adds the elements of the specified collection to the end of the
>   `List<T>`.